# Can I define a function returning another function with a certain signature

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and I enjoy it a lot. But now I struggle with the fact that I am returning functions in my old js codes. So I try to figure how I can define a return type "Function" with a concrete signature. In example like so (note, this does not compile):

```
function getAFunction(): Function(a: string, b: number) {
    return function(a: string, b: number): void {
        // some logic           
    }
}
```

There is also no [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions) for this special case, or have I just overseen it?

Comment: The example in the docs is `var myAdd: (x:number, y:number)=>number`. Note that type annotation syntax is not location-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the syntax is the following:

```
var a = function(): (a: string, b: number) => void {
    return (a: string, b: number) => void {
        // some logic           
    }
}
```

But since the compiler performs type inference, the type annotation is in fact optional:

```
var a = function() {
    return (a: string, b: number) => void {
        // some logic           
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm also new to TypeScript.  Is it preferable to use 'let' instead of 'var' when declaring 'a'?  Or is 'var' better in this case?